# gettext or font issue?

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

I have just moved a website from one host to another and I am having an issue with displaying other languages.  It was working perfectly on the old server but I'm not sure where to start looking for the problem.

[image: The Problem!]

As you can see the fonts display fine in the select box but not in the main page.  I am using a font I have used many times before and never had issues with it.

Any suggestions on were to start looking for the problem?

Comment: Try adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to your `<head>`. These problems usually have nothing to do with PHP

Comment: It is already there... as I said it was working perfectly on the old host. @theomessin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK found the solution on another website not sure why but on this new server I needed an extra piece of code to make gettext work correctly.

```
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
```

Previously I only had,

```
bindtextdomain($domain, "Locale");
textdomain($domain);
```

but for some reason this new server required the extra line?  For interest's sake if anyone can explain the difference I would love to hear.

Comment: Thanks this has just solved the same issue for me :)